# Matlab Round Down

Tags: matlab, rounding

I'm using the round function in matlab to round a variable and get the top and bottom integers of a value. The code im using is as follows:

```
X = 1.8;

Yminusinf = round(X,TieBreaker="fromzero")
%round down
Yplusinf = round(X,TieBreaker="tozero")
%round up
```

The problem is that the result i am getting for both answer is 2. I have copied these equations directly from the official matlab website so im assuming i have used them wrong? Is there a better way to be doing this?

Comment: The `TieBreaker` option dictates how to round 0.5, which is exactly half-way between two integers, and therefore ambiguous how to round it (it's a tie, there's no clear winner). By default, it rounds to the nearest even number I think. This avoids a bias. But sometimes it's nice for even and odd numbers to be treated the same way, hence this option.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are several other ways of achieving this. I'll show you one way using the [`fix()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fix.html) function:

```
function [intLow , intHigh]  = boundingIntegers(num)

intLow  = fix(num) ;
intHigh = intLow + 1*sign(intLow) ;
```

`fix()` will *round toward zero*, regardless of the next digit value (so `1.1` and `1.9` would both be rounded to `1`.

Once you have this *lower* value, the next *higher* integer is obtained by simply adding `1`.

In the code the multiplication by `sign(intLow)` is used so this also works for negative number.

---

You could also find these two bounding integers by using the function:

- [ceil](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ceil.html) - Round toward positive infinity, and/or
- [floor](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/floor.html) - Round toward negative infinity

The principle would be the same, just adapt the gymnastic for dealing with negative numbers if they are part of your possible inputs.

Comment: Actually, with `ceil` or `floor` the logic is simpler... `intLow = floor(num); intHigh = intLow + 1;`.